# Nest groups from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

for hours now I'm searching the web but didn't find a suitable solution yet.

I want to add groups as member to other groups and have a CSV as source.
The CSV looks like (first line is the header)...

```
agroup,bgroup1,bgroup2,bgroup3,...    
a-group1,b-group1,b-group2,b-group3
a-group2,b-group5
a-group3,b-group2,b-group3,b-group4,b-group5,b-group6
a-group4,b-group15,b-group23
```

(...and so forth... Where a-group should represent company roles and b-group corresponding permissions to ressources but that is not the point of this question)

So, following this example  `a-group1` has `b-group1`, `b-group2` and `b-group3` as members.
Now my problem is that I don't know how to iterate through columns 2 to end and ignore empty columns/values.

Other questions here on stackoverflow are about CSV with neatly `user,group` but I can't do this because the CSV covers hundrets of rows and columns.

Someone please help.

**Edit**
Sorry, forgot my code so far.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

$path     = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition  
$newpath  = $path + "\input.csv"
$csv      = @() 
$csv      = Import-Csv -Path $newpath -Delimiter ";"

$csv | Foreach-Object { 
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        Write-Host $_.agroup $property.Value
    } 
}
```

I did a `write-host` for testing.

**Final Edit**

Working code:

```
$csv | Foreach-Object { 
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($property.Value -ne $null -and $property.Value -ne "") {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.agroup -Member $property.Value -WhatIf } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What kind of could did you setup so far? You will just need to check for empty columns/values (e.g. `[String]::IsEmptyOrNull` or `$a -ne $null and $a -ne ""`).

Comment: @Seth thanks, that fixed it: `$csv | Foreach-Object { 
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
  if ($property.Value -ne $null -and $property.Value -ne "") {
        Write-Host $_.agroup $property.Value }
    } 
}`

Comment: Depending on what you do, you might want to use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host` as you can redirect it. Consider posting you Final Code as an answer and accepting it.

Comment: @Josh76, if you have solved the problem you can post your solution as an answer, which is better than adding an edit to the question. It will make it easier for others who find this Q&A in the future to follow what you have done.

Comment: Also, if you can include the header row for the CSV file that would help people (or confirm if there is none).

Comment: Understood, will do, Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code I filtered out the empty values. You might want to remove `whatif` to have it working.

```
$csv | Foreach-Object { 
    foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($property.Value -ne $null -and $property.Value -ne "") {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.agroup -Member $property.Value -WhatIf } 
    } 
}
```